# Gifts ungiven vs. hexproof

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens when my opponent cast [Gifts Ungiven](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGifts%20Ungiven%5d) while I have hexproof (like from [Veil of Summer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeil%20of%20Summer%5d))? Does it fizzle or give them all four of the cards?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you already have hexproof when your opponent attempts to cast [Gifts Ungiven](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGifts%20Ungiven%5d), then Gifts Ungiven cannot be cast because it cannot target an opponent; attempting to do this is an illegal action and results in the game returning to the state before your opponent attempted to cast the spell (CR 601.2c, 601.2e).

If you acquired hexproof between the spell being cast and the spell resolving (e.g. by casting [Veil of Summer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeil%20of%20Summer%5d) in response to Gifts Ungiven going on the stack), then it will fizzle as all its targets are now invalid, or more formally not resolve and be placed into its owner's gravecard (CR 608.2b).

Comment: If someone proposes to cast the card, searches their library for four cards, reveals them, and then their opponent points out that they have hexproof, I take it "return to the state before" means that the cards are shuffled back into the library, even though this isn't exactly the same state?

Comment: @Acccumulation In a competitive situation, you call for a judge because the player should not have searched their library: that is part of the spell _resolving_, not part of it being cast.

Comment: @Accumulation "return to the state before" might mean things like untapping lands which were tapped during the process of casting the spell, and moving the card from the stack back into the player's hand. Usually not much more than that.

Comment: @DavidZ _Nothing_ more than that, with the very small change that any mana abilities can be reversed, not just tapping lands, and stuff like a spell which was cast from the graveyard goes back there rather than going into hand (obviously). Specifically here, actions which caused cards to be revealed from a library explicitly cannot be reversed (all from CR 723.1).

Comment: @Philip Yes, that's exactly what I meant by "usually not much more than that." I intentionally did not try to give a comprehensive list of details.

Comment: While I will definitely be using that typo on purpose in the future, I think it's the "owner's grave*y*ard".  but the rest of the answer is so tight I can't edit it out myself.